# GUI freeze while inserting values into dataGridView using backgroundWorker , C#

Tags: user-interface, freeze

i use backgroundWorker to insert data to datagridview ,
But while inserting values into dataGridView, GUI freezes

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker3.RunWorkerAsync();
        }



private void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            insertodata();
        }

public void insertodata()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<=10;i++ )
            {
                string[] row = new string[9];

                row[0] = "" + i;
                row[1] = "text";
                row[2] = "text";
                row[3] = "text";
                row[4] = "text";
                row[5] = "text";
                row[6] = "text";
                row[7] = "text";
                row[8] = "text";

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

why  GUI freezes ????